# Signed batched transactions are being cancelled but executing in a new transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm running my app in SAFE environment as a custom app and batching my transactions for allowance + swapping.

2/2 signers have signed and the transaction goes through, but the transaction ID with which I'm tracking the transaction doesn't get updated and only show 1/2 signatures. This later gets cancelled.

Meanwhile there is another transaction with the same action that is already completed successfully.

[image]

The transactions that are in the bottom are shown and tracked correctly but the similar action when taken again, it starts to show up as a single `Sent`/`Receieved` transaction rather than a contract interaction.

Both the cases have same code and execution but there was a change in this today.

Can someone help me figure out why this suddenly changed?

Here's a working flow:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xDioBYpeL3JNCPcTZNvoGqcSjx72OD4L/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, SAFE's apis were down: https://status.safe.global/

it's all working as expected now.